# How to show console when running a process?

Tags: c#, bash, process

I'm trying to launch a command in a console window / I'm using a gtk form/
So I've tried to launch it this way:

```
Process p = new Process ();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "bash";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.StartInfo.Arguments ="/tmp/test.sh";
p.Start ();
p.WaitForExit ();
```

but it won't show any thing.
for those who only use windows, it's something like:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
p.StartInfo.Arguments =" c:\\test.bat";
```

I've tried to change UseShellExecute to true but the problem still exist..
Any Ideas??

Comment: define "it won't show any thing."

Comment: I want to show a new console.. but I'm not getting a console window at all

Comment: Does the process actually get created? Can you see it running?

Answer (score 1):

Bash runs the script but if you want to see output, you need to run it in a terminal.

```cs
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "gnome-terminal"; // Replace with whichever terminal you want to use
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.StartInfo.Arguments ="-x bash /tmp/test.sh";
//p.StartInfo.Arguments ="-e \"bash -c /tmp/test.sh;bash\""; // Use this if you want the terminal window to stay open
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```